# Bug? CSS Flexbox gap is applied between two inline text blocks due to an absolutely positioned element between them

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am experiencing unexpected behavior with flexbox and the `gap` property. To my surprise when I "refresh" the DOM by removing the element and adding it back everything works as expected. This leads me to believe that the first paint bugs out somehow and when I "force reload" it fixes itself.

The issue is with a simple `inline-flex` element that contains inline words and an absolutely positioned span between the first two. The `gap` is applied between the first two words but I shouldn't be, since they aren't actual block children elements. Without the span the gap is not created.

The GIF below shows the strange behavior best. What is going on here and is there any way to fix it?

[image]

[Codepen demo](https://cdpn.io/jbelik/fullpage/VwRvJbO?nocache=true&view=)

HTML

```
<div>
  Left <span class="show-for-sr">sr label&nbsp;</span>Right with SR label
</div>
<br>
<div>
  Left Right without SR label
</div>
```

CSS

```
.show-for-sr {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 3.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The gap is applied between the first two words but I shouldn't be, since they aren't actual block children elements.

The gap **should** be applied and this is the correct behavior. The use of `position: absolute` doesn't matter. The HTML code is what you need to consider.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous sequence of child text runs is wrapped in an anonymous block container flex item.

So when having:

```html
<div>
  Left <span class="show-for-sr">sr label&nbsp;</span>Right with SR label
</div>
```

It means that you have 2 "contiguous sequence of child text" plus the span element. So 3 flex items in total and if you make the span `position: absolute` then only 2 flex items are remaining and you get the result you see.

---

The Gold Rule of flexbox is to never make a text container a flexbox container: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p

You should wrap the content within another container:

```html
<div>
  <span>Left <span class="show-for-sr">sr label&nbsp;</span>Right with SR label</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Temani, thanks for you answers! It makes a lot of sense, but how do you explain the behavior where removing the span from DOM and adding it back through the web inspector results in the gap being removed?

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane that's the bug. If you put back the element and you toggle the position: absolute, the gap will appear again. In all the cases, the gap should be there

Comment: I see! Okay makes sense. Very unfortunate, but yeah, I get it.
Thank you very much!

Comment: one more question - I just tried putting the absolutely positioned span before the first word and that doesnt result in the gap being created. Shouldnt it at least create it there as well to be consistent?

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane no, because the absolute element is no more considered when applying the gap. In your code you have one gap between both text (both flex items). You don't have a gap between the first text and the absolute element then another one between the absolute element and the second text. The absolute element is no more part of the flow BUT this won't change the fact that each text has its own block container